# How to make an id from a PHP while echo loop make work with JQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, cordova

I want to make an id reference "logout" work when clicked from my php code. Please this would aid me very well in continuing the project. this method is important because it involves phonegap

php file

The php file gets user details from the database. the logout id is used to call the php page through an AJAX request and then log the user out and redirect them.

```
<?php
session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "*****", "*****", "*****");
//check connection...
if ($con === false) {
    die ("couldn't connect to SQL Server");
}


if (isset($_SESSION['people_email'])){


      $selectdata = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE people_email =       '".$_SESSION['people_email']."'" ;

$query = mysqli_query($con, $selectdata);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {



     echo '<div class="ui fluid card">';
     echo    '<div class="extra content">';
     echo    '<div class="left floated meta">';
     echo       '<a href="#" id="logout">';
     echo   '<i class="remove circle icon"></i>';
    echo "Log out";
    echo '</a>';
    echo    '</div>';
     echo    '<div class="right floated meta">';
    echo       '<a>';
     echo   '<i class="plus icon"></i>';
    echo "Upload a photo";
    echo '</a>';
     echo  '</div>';
     echo  '</div>';
       echo              '<div class="image">';
           echo              '<img src="/images/avatar2/large/kristy.png">';
        echo             '</div>';
           echo          '<div class="content">';
           echo              '<a class="header">'.$row['people_name'].'</a>';
            echo                 '<div class="meta">';
             echo                    '<span class="date">'.$row['people_name'].'</span>';
             echo                '</div>';
             echo            '<div class="description">'.$row['people_email'].'</div>';
                 echo    '</div>';
                 echo    '<div class="extra content">';
                  echo       '<a><i class="send icon"></i>'.$row['people_username'].'</a>';
                  echo       '<a><i class="alarm icon"></i>'.$row['people_username'].'</a>';

                   echo  '</div>';
                echo '</div>' ;
}
}
else {
    echo "no";
}
```

?>

this is the HTML file.

the html file graps the user data for php echo and displays them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
<!-- Path to your custom app styles-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Semantic/semantic.min.css">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />-->
<title>MyApp</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Views -->
<div class="views">
    <!-- Your main view, should have "view-main" class -->
    <div class="view view-main">
    <!-- Pages container, because we use fixed navbar and toolbar, it has additional appropriate classes-->
    <div class="pages navbar-fixed toolbar-fixed">
      <!-- Page, "data-page" contains page name -->

      <div  class="page " data-page="profile">

        <!-- Top Navbar. In Material theme it should be inside of the page-->

<div class="navbar bar-color">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="left"><a href="notification.html" class="external link" style="margin-bottom:35px;"><i class="bell icon"></i></a>
        </div>

        <div class="center"><form><input size="50px" type="search" placeholder="Search"/></form></div>
            <div class="right">
                <!-- Right link contains only icon - additional "icon-only" class-->
                <a href="place.html" class="external link" style="margin-bottom:35px;"> <i class="building outline icon"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



        <!-- Toolbar. In Material theme it should be inside of the page-->
        <div class="toolbar toolbar-bottom bar-color">
          <div class="toolbar-inner">
            <!-- Toolbar links -->
            <a href="index.html" class="external link" style="margin-bottom:35px;"><i class="eye icon"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="external link" style="margin-bottom:35px;"><i class="calendar icon"></i></a>
            <a href="create.html" class="external link" style="margin-bottom:35px;"><i class="plus icon"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="external link" style="margin-bottom:35px;"><i class="user icon"></i></a>

          </div>
        </div>

          <!-- Scrollable page content -->
        <div class="page-content" >
            <div id="profile" style="height:90%; width:90%;margin:auto;position:relative;top:20px;"></div>

          </div>


        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="Semantic/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){


        $.ajax({

            type: 'get',
            url: 'profile.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (response) {

                    $('#profile').html(response);

                }

        });




        $("#logout").click(function() {

   $.ajax({

   type: 'get',
            url: 'logout.php',
            success: function (response) {

                  if (response == "success") {

                       window.location.href="login.html";

                 }else{

                   alert("You were not logged out");

                     }

                }

      });

    });

    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What id are you trying to get? page id?

Comment: @TurtleTread I'm trying to get the link I'd on logout so that the users can log out of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can include data attributes like data-page-id in the log out button html and use jQuery's attr() function to fetch that data.

```
<div id='logout' data-info='some_info'></div>

$('#logout').attr('data-info'); //returns the value
```

But I don't see why you need this extra info since it's just a log out button and you can bind it's id to click event.

Comment: please can you give me an example of how to use the jquery attr () to get an id an the add the click function. Thank you.